# jquery map a hash to a filtered subset

Tags: jquery

So, i had an array and I needed to run that against some conditional then update it so I did something like:

```
 var newitems = myArray.filter(function(x,n){
     return someconditional_is_true;
 }).map(function(arg){
     return "something_new" + arg;
 })
```

That worked like a charm.. but i needed to change my "myArray" to a list (hash) and filtering that list THEN generating an array from it isn't really working.

```
 // NOT working
 var newitems = jQuery.each(myHash, function(x,n){
      if (some_conditional) {
          return 'something_new' + 'n';
      }
 })
```

newitems at the end just holds the looped thru values, not the "return value". I tried ".map" - no luck. I'm fairly certain I am overlooking something minor here.

so, as an example.

```
var myHash = {
    item1 : 'item1value',
    item2 : 'item2value',
    blah : 'item3value'
}


var newitems = jQuery.each(myHash, function(x,n){
    if (x.indexOf('item') != -1){
        return 'myVALUE' + "--" + n;
    }
})

console.log(newitems); // gives me just the myHash in a hash view.


// this just gives me newitems in an array with ALL of myhash stringed. It didn't filter by the conditional.
var newitems = jQuery.map(myHash, function(x,n){
    if (x.indexOf('item') != -1){
       return 'myVALUE' + "--" + n;
    }
})
```

after all is said and done, I expect 'newitems' to have:

```
['myValueitem1',',myValueitem2']
```

Comment: `$.each` won't return an array, returns `this` where `this` is whatever is passed into it. Within `$.each` callback if you return anything, it just goes to next loop unless return `false` which will break the loop. You need `$.map`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each isn't going to honor the return value to build an array. Use `jQuery.map`:

```
var newItems = jQuery.map(myHash, function(value,key){
    if (key.indexOf('item') != -1){
        return 'myVALUE' + "--" + value;
    }
});
```

Comment: hmm. this worked BUT I have nearly the identical code above and it wasn't working.. In my haste I had my args switched.. wow. totally newbed it. thanks!